# как найти точные слова из предложения в mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

как найти точные слова из предложения в mysql, например, в таблице есть столбец где находится категории "music","movie" и в поиске пользователь введет не слово, а допустим, большое предложение "shoping music world movie travel news" а в ответ он получит столбцы "music" и "movie"?

Comment: Поделить введённое на слова и по каждому отдельному слову искать совпадение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда же вы начнете хотя бы просматривать информацию на [первоисточнике](https://www.php.net/docs.php) перед заданием вопроса, а не спрашивать очевидное и описанное в документации? (Не лично к Вам, @Kizat Suleimenov, - ко всем вопрошающим об очевидных вещах.) Ведь даже вся документация на русском языке доступна, читай - не хочу!.. :(

Приведенные варианты решения задачи созданы методом копипаста из примеров документации с незначительными правками.

[Вариант 1.](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-word-count.php)

```php
function find_by_words(string $input_string) {
    $words = str_word_count($input_string, 1);
    if (!empty($words)) {
        $result = db_find_by_words($words);
        return $result;
    }
    return null;
}

function db_find_by_words(array $words) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'database');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        return null;
    }

    $string = implode('% OR category LIKE %', $words);
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE category LIKE %' . $string . '%';

    $query_result = $mysqli->query($query);
    if ($query_result === false) {
        echo 'Query error: ', $mysqli->error, "\n";
        return null;
    }

    $result = [];
    while ($row = $query_result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

[Вариант 2.](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php) Функция db_find_by_words() берется из предыдущего примера.

```php
function find_by_words(string $input_string) {
    $input_string = str_replace(['.', ',', ':', '!', '?'], ' ', trim($input_string));
    $input_string = str_replace('  ', ' ', $input_string);
    $words = explode(' ', $input_string);

    if (!empty($words)) {
        $result = db_find_by_words($words);
        return $result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Использованные методы PHP [mysqli::query()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php), [mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

[Используемый оператор MySQL LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

P.S. Если очень захочется посмотреть, что находится в переменной, то есть еще [var_dump()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.var-dump.php).

P.P.S. Если после **тщательного** изучения документации по указанным мною ссылкам останутся вопросы - я не виноват! RTFM рулит.

P.P.P.S. Чувствую себя соавтором методички для студентов первого курса обучения... :(

Comment: в предыдущей главное только не забудьте написать, что за прямую подстановку пользовательского ввода в запроса автоматом на пересдачу